# Flex/Flash BorderContainer click through

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex4

I have two bordercontainers in flex4 on top of each other.  A BorderContainer containing my text and one underneath containing Images.  Both use Greensock TransformManager to control the contents of each (a different flex TransformManager for each).

I currently can't select the image underneath the text bordercontainer without changing the depth a bring the images border container above the text.

Please does anyone know how I can click through the text borderContainer to the images underneath?

Thanks
David

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need your text `BorderContainer` to be interactable, in other words you don't want any mouse interaction with it, you can set the `mouseEnabled` property of the text `BorderContainer` to false like so:

```
<s:BorderContainer id="textBorderContainer" mouseEnabled="false">
    // text children here
</s:BorderContainer>
```

Or if you add your `BorderContainer` dynamically, without MXML, set it like this:

```
textBorderContainer.mouseEnabled = false;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, unfortunately I need the text in the bordercontainer to selectable